# all searches comes back w/ epoch time (DEC 31 1969)

Tags: search

I have my own environment setup w/ [Apache Solr Search | Drupal.org](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr).

Whenever I input a standard search inside of a search box, majority (if not all) returned results appears in epoch time (DEC 31 1969), needless to say we don't have this date inside of our content.

our environment is using: php-5.3.3 (RHEL6), apache-solr-1.4.1 and apachesolr-6.x-1.8.

any suggestions?

NOTE: I posted same question on Drupal Groups as well: [epoch time (DEC 31 1969) | Drupal Groups](https://groups.drupal.org/node/368348)

Comment: Where are you searching from and what are you searching? Is this your own implementation or a module?

Comment: I have my own environment up and running w/ apache's solr

Comment: Where is the search date data coming from?

Comment: from indexed pages (content) of my site.

Comment: Assuming the index pages are nodes, if a node doesn't have the 'created' column populated in the table for each node, any nodes without that value will return DEC 31 1969. I'd recommend populating each node with an estimated created time if they don't have one. Use this MySQL query to get a count of how many nodes do not have their created times set: `SELECT COUNT(nid) FROM node WHERE created IS NULL`

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein that query returns 0 count. I also hooked same SOLR instance (using same module and everything) to another environment (biggest difference is running on RHEL5 instead of RHEL6 and running PHP-5.2.17 instead of PHP-5.3.3.) and I'm _NOT_ getting `DEC 31, 1969`.